# Como puedo cambiar los estatus de los productos despues del proceso de checkout de completed a procesing?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

este es mi primera pregunta en esta plataforma. Tengo un problema con mi pagina de woocommerce, cuando efectuo el pago de un producto este se registra en el inventario como COMPLETADO, y me gustaria que no se guarde asi, me gustaria que este con el estado PROCESANDO, pero he intentando crear una funcion para la misma y el resultado me medio funciono, pero luego los productos no se podian pasar a ningun otro estado que no fuera PROCESANDO.

El codigo es este:

```
function actualizar_estado_pedido_completado($order_id){

    // Variable Woo
    global $woocommerce;

    // Array con metodos de pago
    $paymentMethods = array('paypal');

    if ( !$order_id ) return;

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( !in_array( $order->payment_method, $paymentMethods ) )
    $order->update_status( 'processing' );
}

add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','actualizar_estado_pedido_completado');
```

Muchas gracias de ante mano y espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que estás confundiendo estados de pedidos con estados de productos, que no hay en woocommerce. Cuando se realiza un pedido, el pedido pasa al estado que le hayas dicho que deje después de terminar el pago (lo puedes revisar en métodos de pago). Y este estado, después puedes pasarlo a procesando, enviado y completado. Si el pedido pasa directamente a completado, se supone que ya ha sido terminado. Creo que deberías explicar un poco mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, al final el problema resulto ser la pasarela de pago que justamente después de procesar el pago el mismo plugin usa una función de woocommers para pasar el estado a COMPLETADO, lo que hice fue editar esto directamente en el plugin. De igual manera gracias por tu respuesta!!!